# delete multiple strings based on string in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have some webhook and the return response is

```
message: 'uat.chatbot: Klhhn'

message: 'Zulkifli Raihan: Hello'
```

The Example :

> message: 'name from sender: The Message'

How can i get The Message in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex.  I assumed that your:

```
message: 'Zulkifli Raihan: Hello'
```

was actually a property on an object, but the regex below can be modified if the whole thing was a string too.

```js
const data = {
    message: 'Zulkifli Raihan: Hello'
};

const matches = data.message.match(/:\s*([^:]+)$/);
console.log(matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`message.split(":").slice(-1).join("").trim()`

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.